#targetcli g-io-error-quark: Could not connect: No such file or directory (1)
Targetcli not working inside fedora: latest container even though it is installed while creating an image. Getting the below error.
#targetcli g-io-error-quark: Could not connect: No such file or directory (1)

I want to use targetcli inside the container, to create target and configure iqn, acl and manage iscsi.
